# MapBox scroll page on touch

Tags: javascript, touch, mapbox

I'm trying to implement MapBox on a layout which fills 100% of the page. I've disable the map zoom options but the problems comes when trying to scroll on touch devices where the map fills the viewport. Can I override this or have the browser treat it like an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example has been improved: the line that was missing is:

`if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();`

This will prevent the map from killing tap events on touch devices.

Comment: This "disables the tap handler" as described in the [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/disable-zooming-panning/) - does not disable the map dragging on touch devices the OP asks about

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can stop the Mapbox listeners from preventing default actions by setting the leaflet function to do nothing:

```
L.DomEvent.preventDefault = function(e) {return;}
```

To remove the outline placed around the element by the browser that otherwise would have been prevented, you can add:

```
*:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
  -webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
}
```

This allowed scrolling on touch devices for me, though I've only tested on Android.  Note that this may have other consequences on your application - these could probably be prevented by going into mapbox.js and removing this call from only the listeners that you need.

Comment: Great! This worked fine for me however another user on iPad now has problems tapping on tooltip icons. They won't stay open unless I add an alert() click event. I'm stuck on a way to fix this.

Comment: This seems extremely heavy-handed. You're basically nuking all functionality on the map entirely. There are options to control each element you might want to disable while leaving the others operational.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the rest of the listeners [as in this example](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/disable-zooming-panning/) - the one you probably still have is `dragging`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution via CSS: `pointer-events: none;`

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to dynamically enable / disable map box scrolling / zooming etc depending on page size (as I did) you can try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', updateMap);
});

function updateMap() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width < 768) {
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
    map.dragging.disable();
    if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();
  }
  else {
    map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
    map.dragging.enable();
    if (map.tap) map.tap.enable();
  }
}
```

Replace 768 by the appropriate magic number for your layout. Assumes jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `dragging` parameter in mapbox is that it controls both the click-and-hold dragging with a mouse or other pointing device **and** the swiping motion drag using touch. Not sure any of the other answers clarify that as the main issue.

The heart of the problem that I think the OP is getting at is that we all like the click-dragging and think it's easy to use, but we don't like the touch-dragging because it interferes with the ability to scroll the entire page.

This is the line of code I ended up using. It depends on Modernizr and jQuery, but you could write something similar without them if you needed to.

```
// disable dragging the map on touch devices only
if ($('html').hasClass('touch')) map.dragging.disable();
```