# MapBox dragging.disable function blocks the scroll of the page on mobile

Tags: javascript, dictionary, scroll, touch, mapbox

I´m working with a MapBox map and I have the following problem:

On mobile the map doesn´t fill all the page because I need to show other things after it.

I´m using `map.dragging.disable();` and this prevents dragging the map as expected, but also scroll it. So, how can I disable that dragging event without blocking the normal scroll behavior? I need to be able to scroll as is the map were an image, but I don´t want to do [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-image/).

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075867/mapbox-scroll-page-on-touch) but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help but covering mapbox manually with overlay does work.

```
<!-- Wrapper -->
<div style="position: relative;">
  <!-- Mapbox object -->
  <div id="mapbox"></div>
  <!-- Overlay -->
  <div style="height: 200px; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Additionally you toggle the overlay display from block to none in order to make the maps draggable again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this issue as well. Out of curiousity, what version of mapbox were you using? I don't remember this being an issue in past versions. I'm on v2.2.1.

I'm using [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) on my site and the solution that I implemented was to apply a `z-index: -1` property to the map container when the `.touchevents` class is present. This way you don't need to add uneccesary markup to your page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.touchevents #map {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

If you're not using Modernizr I would encourage you to but if you can't for whatever reason you could just apply the z-index on smaller browser widths with media queries. Less desirable but better than nothing.